# python: how to sort a list of letters and numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting, numbers, letters

Such as, `lista = [300KB, 12MB, 100KB, 1GB]`, i want to process `lista`, then change it to `[100KB, 300KB, 12MB, 1GB]`

How to sort it using simple method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"lista" has to be a list of strings.
`sorted` is your friend here. [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

```
def memory_mult(text):
    memory = {'KB':1024, 'MB':1024**2, 'GB':1024**3}
    num = text[:-2]
    mult = text[-2:]
    return int(num)*memory[mult]

sorted(lista, key=memory_mult)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the simplest method i see.

Comment: using `float(num)` instead of `int(num)` may be robust.